# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Authorization of Windows users is slow, can we speed it up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, windows-authentication

Our ASP.NET MVC 3 intranet application makes use of Windows user authentication, and also demands that users are in a certain role to access administrative sections (authorization). While all this works, we find that checking a user's role membership is really slow (~20 seconds). We use either the `User.IsInRole` method or `AuthorizeAttribute`. Even if we check against the local Administrators group ('BUILTIN\Administrators') instead of an AD group it's still as slow.

Now, is there some recommended scheme we may follow in order to speed up user authorization? Is it common for instance to cache a user's authorization status in a database? Is there, more fundamentally, something fishy going on since authorizing against a local group ('Administrators') is this slow?

**EDIT:**

The Web server is running on Windows 2008 R2 SP1 x64, .NET 4.0, IIS 7.5, 4 GB RAM. I am getting the same latency querying for the user role membership on my development machine however, so it looks like the issue is independent of the machine the app is running on. DBMS shouldn't matter I think, as the time is spent querying whether the user is a member of 'BUILTIN\Administrators' (to simplify the problem, I'm just checking this local group).

Comment: Was it always like this? slow?

Comment: @Pabloker Actually, I don't recall. It wasn't that long ago that we introduced the authorization bit, and when it first started slowing down I figured it was due to the VM hosting the server. It's just thanks to installing MiniProfiler today that I realized just how slow it is and why.

Comment: Ok. Could you put your system configuration? DBMS, Server OS, IIS, etc?

Comment: Are you using your own MembershipProvider and RoleProvider or are you using the ones provided with the framework?

Comment: @StefanBossbaly We're using `System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider` for the `roleManager` element in Web.config, I assume this is the RoleProvider?

Comment: Could you put your Web.config's `<configuration>` section?

Comment: @Pabloker OK, have a gander: http://pastebin.com/izTGGQLQ.

Comment: ugh! I can't access because my company's proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood ASP.NET MVC Windows user authentication is doing the same thing Web Forms does. I don't know of any performance problems using the frameworks MembershipProvider and RoleProvider with Web Forms or MVC. To debug this I'd create the simplest Web Forms (and MVC) projects and find out where all the time is spent. It could be your AD server is slow or that the first attempt to authenticate is timing out.

Comment: We've configured `System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider` for the `roleManager` element in Web.config. The time is spent checking role membership, for instance via the call `User.IsInRole(@"BUILTIN\Administrators")`. I don't know how to drill down any further than that as the `User` object is of the standard library class `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal`.

Comment: @aknuds1 not sure if this would give you anything more, but you could; enable .net framework source stepping...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray For some reason, the source for the relevant method (User.IsInRole) isn't available, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684358/cant-step-through-net-method-system-web-security-roleprincipal-isinrole-due-to.

Comment: @aknuds1 you could try reflector (or free alternative) and pick through the code to see what its doing but again not sure if this would give you anything more...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Thanks, Reflector might be worth a shot.

Comment: I'm thinking the issue is just that the AD server is slow. From the decompiled (by Reflector) source I gather that all the user's roles are queried for, so the AD server would be hit regardless if I'm checking a local role. I suppose I should look for a way to authorize only locally.